# Why did Pavlo Tychyna have to reject his Nobel Prize nomination?

Tags: pavlo-tychyna

According to the introduction to the author of *Pavlo Tychnya: the Complete Early Poetry Collection*,

> Tychnya was rewarded with the Stalin Prize for literature in 1941 for his poetry in support of the state and when nominated for the Nobel Prize in Literature was forced to reject the nomination.

Why did he have to reject it?

Comment: you know it was such a country where a man was afraid to be nominated for the Nobel prize in literature

Comment: @Andra Why were they so opposed to them getting a Nobel Prize?

Comment: he was Ukrainian, nomination would not be for sovietic literary works, so in that country he could end in a camp in Mordovia or be forced to exile. I understand that he refused to be nominated.

Comment: @Andra Not sure I follow... he was given an award for writing pro-government poetry (apparently at least partially to avoid the fate you were describing) in his later life. Why wouldn't they want him to win a Nobel Prize for that? Or was his nomination for his early work?

Comment: I never before heard his name, so it's a bit strange that I try to find some info and explain: 1) he was Ukrainian, 2) the nomination would be for his earlier literary works (not published in soviet time), 3) and it was initiated by Omeljan Pritsak, who was Ukrainian in exile and the founder of the Harvard Institute of Ukrainian Studies. No, the soviet state did not need such nomination.

Comment: and, please, correct the spelling of his name in English - Tychyna (the tag also)